# CentOS 6 beta release

Tags: centos6

I would like to start testing and development on **[CentOS 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#Release_history)**.

Is it available, or when is it due for release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RHEL 6 was only released today. CentOS is usually 2-3 months behind as they have to strip any licensed material and recompile. Why not try Fedora 14 while you're waiting?

See the [CentOS](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=centos) and [Red Hat](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat) previous release dates.

Comment: Ohh im not a big fan of Fedora for servers.. Ubuntu is my desktop favourite..

For Servers,
im a die hard CentOS fan, followed up strongly by debian..

You really think it will take 2-3 months? even for a beta?

Comment: CentOS don't make them as betas - they don't develop, just recompile as far as I'm aware. As for not using Fedora for servers - why consider using a new distribution on release date if that's the case? There's always going to be a few bugs to iron out.

Comment: Im basically testing out a future setup..
i wanted to start standardising for the future project with some "advanced" currently beta or new release software..

So it would be nice to start on something i wont need to change..
even if i hit a few bugs..
But i think your right.. Centos does the rebadge-recompile thing..
so there probabaly wont be a beta seen publicly..
Cheers

Comment: CentOS only do beta releases for major versions, like this one. As documented here: https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=25878

Comment: It's late June, and I'm surprised to see that no progress has been made on this. RHEL is already at the 6.1 stage.

Answer (score 5):

This is what they announced on Twitter today:

> There are, ofcourse, no release dates.
>   Its done when its done. But if you
>   need something to plan against - think
>   4 to 6 weeks. #centos6

Source: http://twitter.com/CentOS/status/2685726453932032

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are posting status updates to this page semi-regularly:
https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=25878&forum=53

The most recent as of this writing was posted on 2011/02/22:

> Yesterday (Tuesday February 22, 2011), I received a status update from Karanbir regarding the progress of CentOS 6.0 and he has asked me to post it to this thread.
>
> Quote:
>
> 6.0: Due to time issues, I'm not updating the Audit Status page [1] at the
>   moment. However there has been movement on the CentOS 6 build-front. 
>   I think I'll leave updating that page until 4.9 and 5.6 are out of the door.

The Audit page they refer to is available here:
http://wiki.centos.org/QaWiki/6/AuditStatus

Answer (score 0):

The [QA process](http://wiki.centos.org/QaWiki) is open, but do expect to do some actual work helping to get CentOS 6 ready for GA.

Comment: How can i help???

Comment: Ask in #centos-devel on Freenode. http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=8